# why the max drop down item property doesn't work in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a ComboBox with about 30 items,
and when the user wants to view the drop down items, almost all of items shows, If I set the property `MaxDropDownItems` to 4 it appears not to have an effect. What should I do ?

Comment: How does it not working? Is it WinForm? WebForm? WPF?

Comment: You forgot to post the actual code.

Comment: please show the actual code that is giving you the problem

Comment: @DawidFerenczy it don't have a code it's just a property that doesen't work, whit the help of Ian my problem just solve

Comment: @MarkHall it don't have a code it's just a property that doesen't work, whit the help of Ian my problem just solve

Comment: why 2 vote down? can you tell me reason of this vote down that I consider it in my next questions ?? tanks

Comment: I didn't down-voted your question, but I would say if you check the Stack Overflow's help on asking questions you will find an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be really sure, consider of changing the IntegralHeight to false (default is true) and the ComboBoxStyle to DropDownList (default is DropDown) as well:

```
ComboBox.IntegralHeight = false;
ComboBox.MaxDropDownItems = 4;
ComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

This way, you forcefully control your ComboBox display.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `ComboBox.MaxDropDownItems` Property to 30 to make all `Items` visible (re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.maxdropdownitems(v=vs.110).aspx)